# Deployment error: "authenticationConfig.xml contains duplicated realm named: wl_anonymousUserRealm"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I am working on an app using Workight 6.1 with SQL adapters and DB2 database. I deployed it and the deploy process works well without problems.

But when I go to the Worklight Console using `http://server-host:9080/TicketWorklight/console`, it fails with the following error:

> Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Worklight Console
>   initialization failed.Logged Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   conf/authenticationConfig.xml contains duplicated realm named:
>   wl_anonymousUserRealm

This is the comlete authenticationConfig.xml file:

```
<!-- Uncomment the next element to protect the worklight console and the first section in securityTests below. -->
 <staticResources>
<!-- <resource id="worklightConsole" securityTest="WorklightConsole">
        <urlPatterns>/console*</urlPatterns>
     </resource> 
    -->
    <resource id="subscribeServlet" securityTest="SubscribeServlet">
        <urlPatterns>/subscribeSMS*;/receiveSMS*</urlPatterns>
    </resource>
</staticResources> 

 <securityTests>
    <!-- 
    <customSecurityTest name="WorklightConsole">
        <test realm="WorklightConsole" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    </customSecurityTest>

    <mobileSecurityTest name="mobileTests">
        <testAppAuthenticity/> 
        <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
        <testUser realm="myMobileLoginForm" />
    </mobileSecurityTest>

    <webSecurityTest name="webTests">
        <testUser realm="myWebLoginForm"/>
    </webSecurityTest>

    <customSecurityTest name="customTests">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
    </customSecurityTest>
    -->
    <customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
        <test realm="SubscribeServlet" isInternalUserID="true"/>
    </customSecurityTest>       

</securityTests> 

<realms>
    <realm name="SampleAppRealm" loginModule="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
    </realm>

    <realm name="WorklightConsole" loginModule="requireLogin">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.FormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        <onLoginUrl>/console</onLoginUrl>
    </realm>

    <realm name="SubscribeServlet" loginModule="rejectAll">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.HeaderAuthenticator</className>          
    </realm>

    <!-- For websphere -->
    <!-- realm name="WASLTPARealm" loginModule="WASLTPAModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereFormBasedAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="login-page" value="/login.html"/>
        <parameter name="error-page" value="/loginError.html"/>
    </realm -->

    <!-- For User Certificate Authentication -->
    <!-- realm name="wl_userCertificateAuthRealm" loginModule="WLUserCertificateLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateAuthenticator</className>
        <parameter name="dependent-user-auth-realm" value="WASLTPARealm" />
        <parameter name="pki-bridge-class" value="com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateEmbeddedPKI" />
        <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-file-path" value="/opt/ssl_ca/ca.p12"/> 
        <parameter name="embedded-pki-bridge-ca-p12-password" value="capassword" />
    </realm -->

</realms>

<loginModules>
    <loginModule name="StrongDummy">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="requireLogin">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.SingleIdentityLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <loginModule name="rejectAll">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.RejectingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule>

    <!-- For websphere -->
    <!-- loginModule name="WASLTPAModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.WebSphereLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule -->

    <!-- Login module for User Certificate Authentication -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="WLUserCertificateLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.UserCertificateLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->


    <!-- For enabling SSO with no-provisioning device authentication -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->


    <!-- For enabling SSO with auto-provisioning device authentication -->
    <!-- <loginModule name="MySSO" ssoDeviceLoginModule="WLDeviceAutoProvisioningLoginModule">
        <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.NonValidatingLoginModule</className>
    </loginModule> -->
</loginModules>
```

Comment: And the Worklight version is...?

Comment: Additionally, edit the question and add your full authenticationConfig.xml file

Comment: Is this a remote server or Worklight Studio? Can you try with a blank new project to verify this is working correctly?

Comment: The problem still remains using blank project. The file authenticationConfig.xml file generated by worklight studio

Comment: Where are you running your application, though? is this a remote server (where you need to deploy first the Worklight .war file and deploy the JEE file as well as the .wlapp file), or are you running it IN Workilght Studio?

Comment: I deploy it on a remote server using Server Configuration Tool

Comment: Do you have only 1 Worklight project deployed? Could it be that you have 2 projects and you mistakenly points to the other one?

Comment: Could you please provide full steps for reproduction? from creating the Worklight project to deploying it in the remote server? We'd like to try and recreate this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a resolution that fixed my problem. Referenced here

[worklight console for app not working after deploying new war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169247/worklight-console-for-app-not-working-after-deploying-new-war/26182209?noredirect=1#comment41051988_26182209)